# Nearby.Messages.handleIntent(PendingIntent intent, MessageListener messageListener) not found

Tags: android, background, google-beacon-platform, google-nearby

In [Nearby Messages API for Android](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-beacon-messages#subscribe_in_the_background), to get Beacon messages in background (once subscribed to BLE), it says:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Nearby.Messages.handleIntent(intent, new MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFound(Message message) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Found message via PendingIntent: " + message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(Message message) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Lost message via PendingIntent: " + message);
        }
    });
}
```

But the function `Nearby.Messages.handleIntent(PendingIntent intent, MessageListener messageListener)` cannot be found: [see on Android Studio](http://i.imgsafe.org/c093893.png)

Comment: Do you have the latest Google Play Services (check SDK Manager)? Have you tried restarting Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Nearby Api version 8.3.0 : `com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.3.0`. But the function `Nearby.Messages.handleIntent(PendingIntent intent, MessageListener messageListener)` which allows to listen to beacon messages in background was  in  the release 3.4.0.

Thanks to MahlerFive.